# Cross-validation using Knime

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, knime

I am using Knime and I've created a Neural Network using MLP (MultiLayer Perceptron). It works fine. You may ignore all the yellow nodes as all they do is reformat the data sheet.

[image]

This works, but I would like to incorporate Cross Validation into the mix. There is a lack of working examples and so I am struggling. I am looking at `X-Partitioner` and `X-Aggregator` nodes but I have no idea how to use them in my network.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: There is an example with SVM Learner/Predictor in the public example server: `04_Analytics`/`11_Optimization`/`01_Cross_Validation_with_SVM` That should be a good starting point, but you should read the `X-Partitioner`, `X-Aggregator` node documentation too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was quite simple. `X-partitioner` node basically replaces the `Partitioner` node. The `X-Aggregator` node is placed after the MLP Predictor. The `X-Aggregator` node is in charge of looping the neural network.

[image]